# What is the Best way to convert org.json.JSONObject to javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob?

Tags: java, blob, json

Currently I use following method, but I do not like it:

```
JSONObject formJsonObj = new JSONObject();
formJsonObj.put("whatever", "whatever is inside");

ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
o.writeObject(formJsonObj );
byte[] byteArray = b.toByteArray();

SerialBlob blob = new SerialBlob(byteArray);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: there must be better ways than to apply Java serialization to a JSON object

Answer (score 2):

The main reason you might not like you method is that JSONObject is not serializable and writeObject(formJsonObj ) is throwing an exception. Java's ObjectOutputStream requires that the Objects it serializes implements Serializable.

I would recommend using JSONObject's toString method as it will return the text based json representation in its minimized form. A simple implemention would look like this.

```
public static SerialBlob JSONToBlob(JSONObject object) throws SQLException {
    String text = object.toString();
    text = text == null ? "{}" : text;
    return new SerialBlob(text.getBytes());
}

public static JSONObject blobToJSON(SerialBlob blob) throws SerialException, IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream result = blob.getBinaryStream();
    String jsonString = new String(toByteArray(result));
    return new JSONObject(jsonString);
}

private static byte[] toByteArray(InputStream result) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;
    while(( i = result.read())== -1) {
        out.write(i);
    }
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Json to create a writer and finaly converter the string in the writer to byteArray

```
    JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject();
    myJson.put("key", "value");
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    Json.createWriter(writer).write(myjson);
    SerialBlob blob = new SerialBlob(writer.toString().getBytes());
```

**From SerialBlob to String**

```
JsonReader reader=Json.createReader(serialBlob.getBinaryStream());
JsonObject myJson=reader.readObject();
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The write method doesn't accept org.json.JSONObject.